# Android-x86. Как подключить к Eclipse в качестве эмулятора?

Tags: android

Установил Android-x86. Не пойму, как подключить его к Eclipse в качестве эмулятора?

Comment: эмм..Эклипс в качестве эмулятора?

Answer (score 1):

Без проблем, давайте я поищу за вас, раз уж вам религия не позволяет.

1. [Официальный мануал на сайте проекта](http://www.android-x86.org/documents/debug-howto).
2. [Статья на хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/119931/).
3. Ещё одна [статья на хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/130201/).
4. Вы не поверите, но ещё одна [статья на хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/154395/).

Comment: 3. Ещё одна статья на хабре - эта ссылка мне очень хорошо подошла! спасибо!

Comment: Похоже сеть то не работает! Можно как-нибудь настроить обычную сеть, чтобы работать по сокетам?

Comment: Гм. Вы вообще статьи по вышеприведённым ссылкам читали? Там вопрос настройки сети на эмуляторе вполне подробно рассматривается.